# Rails gives error on load: Missing helper file helpers/profiles_helper.rb -- but the file is the

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When I connect to localhost:3000 I get this error message:

```
AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods::MissingHelperError in PoemsController#index
Missing helper file helpers/profiles_helper.rb
```

However, the file is there: in irb,

```
2.0.0-p195 :001 > f = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'helpers', 'profiles_helper.rb'))
 => #   <File:/Users/carlson/Dropbox/prog/rails_projects/verz/app/helpers/profiles_helper.rb>
```

Also, when I run rake, I get this:

```
$ rake
rake aborted!
Missing helper file helpers/profiles_helper.rb
/Users/carlson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-     4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:137:in `rescue in block in modules_for_helpers'
/Users/carlson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:134:in `block in modules_for_helpers'
/Users/carlson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:130:in `map!'
 /Users/carlson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:130:in `modules_for_helpers'
```

Here is more of the error message from the browser

```
Extracted source (around line #1):

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
end
```

I am stumped!

Jim

Comment: Where are you using your helper method?

Comment: Can you post the relevant source from PoemsController?

Comment: cortex -- thank you for the question!  In profiles_helper.rb, there was an extraneous require 'utility' from a another project (from which I had copied this profiles_helper.rb). Once I removed that file, rails loaded profile_helper.rb.